# MySQL created with Helm can't connect with non root user

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am trying to connect to database I have deployed with Helm.
What I have is a **mysql.yaml** file:

```
auth:
  database: db_host
  username: hamuto
  password: motdepasse
  rootPassword: rootpass
image:
  debug: true
```

I install my MySQL database with the command: ✅

> helm install mysql bitnami/mysql -f mysql.yaml -f mysql-pv.yaml -f mysql-pvc.yaml

## What happens when the MySQL is deployed:

This will then output some commands to connect to the database:

> echo Username: root
> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default mysql -o jsonpath="{.data.mysql-root-password}" | base64 --decode)

- If I try to echo the variable **MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD** I get the password **rootpass**. ✅
- If I try the same thing with the **MYSQL_PASSWORD** non root password, by changing the jsonpath, I can find the password **motdepasse**. ✅

I run a pod as a client with the command: ✅

> kubectl run mysql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image  docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0.29-debian-10-r15 --namespace default --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --command -- bash

Inside the pod, I run the following command to connect to the database as root : ✅

> mysql -h mysql.default.svc.cluster.local -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"

## The issue:

Trying to connect with non root user doesn't work. ❌

> mysql -h mysql.default.svc.cluster.local -u hamuto -pmotdepasse

Doesn't work. ❌

I have checked the helm file template with the command:

> helm template mysql .

Nothing weird was shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Persistent Volume, when I deleted the mysql with :

> helm delete mysql

The PV and PVC stayed, which prevented the new user to be created.
I just had to delete it, so I did:

> kubectl delete pvc --all